# Can i call SetEvent() on an HANDLE returned by CreateFile()?

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++

I am using ReadDirectoryChangesW() in a thread to monitor file changes and i'm passing the handle returned by CreateFile() to ReadDirectoryChangesW(). I am using the same handle in WaitForSingleObject() to wait for file changes in the directory. Can i call SetEvent() on this HANDLE to manually exit the thread?

Answer (score 4):

A file handle can be used as a synchronization object in a call to `WaitForSingleObject`. That doesn't imply that you can use any synchronization object specific API calls, such as `SetEvent` on it. The documentation for [SetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211.aspx) is clear on the subject:

> *hEvent* [in]
>
> A handle to the event object. The [CreateEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396.aspx) or [OpenEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684305.aspx) function returns this handle.

The canonical solution to terminating a thread that is waiting for events is to create an additional event object, and use [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx) inside the thread. When the thread needs to terminate, you call `SetEvent` on that event object. The return value of `WaitForMultipleObjects` reports, which synchronization object was signaled.